# How to make html and js to remember users dark theme setting

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for my discord bot (https://beast-bot.ga) i made a dark theme feature which will switch the website from light mode to dark mode but when i refresh the page the website will switch back to light mode is there any way to fix this like saving the data in a cookie or something.

my js

```
var icon = document.getElementById("icon");

       icon.onclick = function(){
        document.cookie = "theme=dark";
          document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
          if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
             icon.src = "images/sun.png";
          }else{
             icon.src = "images/moon.png"
          }
        }
```

style.css

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@700&family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo:400,700");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:wght@300&display=swap");
/*Desktop*/
:root{

  --normal:url(images/wave-haikei.svg);
  --darks: url(images/wave-black.svg);
  --text-theme: white;
  --cont2: url(images/wave-rot.PNG);
}
.dark-theme{
    --normal: url(images/wave-black.svg);
    --text-theme: white;
    --cont2: url(images/black-wave-rot.svg);
}

/*Desktop reals*/
@media screen and (min-width: 1301px){
  .container {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: var(--normal);

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
  }
  .title {
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 72px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    user-select: none;
  }
  /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
  .topnav {
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
  .topnav a {
    float: left;
    color: #0087ca;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  /* Change the color of links on hover */
  .topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
  }

  /* Add a color to the active/current link */
  .topnav a.active {
    color: #0087ca;
  }
  .title .img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    left: 600px;
    bottom: 250px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .infotit {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .hover-underline-animation a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    color: #0087ca;
  }
  
  .hover-underline-animation a:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    height: 6px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0087ca;
    transform-origin: bottom right;
    transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
  }

  .hover-underline-animation a:hover:after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: bottom left;
  }
  .trust {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    color: var(--text-theme);
    text-align: center;
  }
  .info .quote {
    font-size: 36px;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 100px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .info .btn {
   text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    
  }
  .info .quoto {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 36px;
    bottom: 50px;
    position: relative;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .info .h11 {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .info .h11 .h33 {
    color: red;
  }
  .info .h11 .muchmore_txt {
    color: red;
  }
  .f_txt {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .more_txt {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: var(--text-theme);
  }
  .footer {
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 100px;
  }

  /*MORE CONTENTS*/
  .container2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-image: var(--cont2);
    object-fit: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: auto;
 

  }
  
  .title2 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: groove;
  }
  .hideme {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .minecraft {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  }
  .mcimg {
    width: 605px;
    height: 300px;
    border-color: red;
  }
  .mcpara {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .joke {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  }
  .jokeimg {
    width: 805px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .jokepara {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .roast {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  }
  .roastimg {
    width: 705px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .roastpara {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .animegif {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  }
  .animeimg {
    width: 605px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .animapara {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .meme {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  }
  .memeimg {
    width: 705px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .memepara {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

my index.html
https://pastebin.com/jKMT14Nk

Comment: You can just use local storage you don't need to use cookies

Comment: There are so many questions here on StackOverflow regarding that topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't tested it. But I guess it should work. So basically what you do is on page load you check if there is an item *theme* inside of the localstorage that has the value *dark* if so, you toggle the theme.

Otherwise you toggle the value of the property *theme* inside of the localstorage, as well as the class on your body and the icon as soon as you click on it. Sadly you didn't provide any HTML that's why I couldn't test it.

This should completely replace the js you posted above.

```
const themeToggle = document.getElementById("icon");
const darkThemeClass = 'dark-theme';

const toggleTheme = () => {
  setTheme(document.body.classList.contains(darkThemeClass));
}

const setTheme = (theme) => {
  localStorage.setItem('theme', theme ? 'light' : 'dark');
  themeToggle.src =  `images/${!theme ? 'sun' : 'moon'}.png`;
  document.body.classList.toggle(darkThemeClass, !theme);
}

themeToggle.addEventListener('click', toggleTheme);

(() => localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark' && setTheme(false))();
```

Comment: here is index.html https://pastebin.com/jKMT14Nk

Comment: It should work fine tho. Did you try to implement it?

Comment: wait a minute the icon is not changing please fix that too

Comment: The Icon should be changing. It throws errors for me because it can't find them. Just look in the lines where I set the source maybe the paths or the files are named differently.

Comment: its all are right

Comment: here are the images https://beast-bot.ga/images/moon.png and https://beast-bot.ga/images/sun.png

Comment: Updated the code.

Comment: thanks working do you have discord if you have can i contact you if i have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `localStorage` would help?

`localStorage` keeps all the things you need to save.

For more info, go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

###### Edit:

```js
function toggleModes(bool) {
  if (new Number(bool) == 0) {
    localStorage.setItem("isDarkMode", "0")
  } else if (new Number(bool) == 1) {
    localStorage.setItem("isDarkMode", "1")
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem("isDarkMode", "1")
  }
}

if (localStorage.getItem("isDarkMode") == null) {
  toggleModes(/* default setting */)
}
```

Comment: Uh sorry but can you give me code?